# Best Way For Estimating Parameters Of Hidden Markov Process

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

Parameter estimation is not stable.
First, make a model.

```
proc[n_] := HiddenMarkovProcess[(#1/Total[#1] & )[
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, {n}]], (#1/Total[#1] & ) /@ 
    RandomReal[{1, 10}, {n, n}], Table[NormalDistribution[RandomReal[], 
     RandomReal[{0.01, 1}]], n]];

proc2[n_] := HiddenMarkovProcess[Table[a[i], {i, 1, n}], 
   Table[b[i, j], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}], 
   Table[NormalDistribution[c[i], d[i]], {i, 1, n}]];

pr = proc[3]
```

> HiddenMarkovProcess[{0.148376, 0.42108, 
>     0.430544}, {{0.458023, 0.104694, 0.437283}, {0.160391, 0.462158, 
>      0.377451}, {0.375321, 0.269047, 0.355633}}, {NormalDistribution[
>      0.4253, 0.118768], NormalDistribution[0.278537, 0.832337],    NormalDistribution[0.658421, 0.730663]}]

```
RandomFunction[pr, {0, 100}, 3] // Histogram
```

[image: 1]

Estimating the transition probability and the emission distribution,
then check the absolute error of trans-Probability between true value and estimated one.
here,`proc2` is model which is estimated,and `proc[3]` is initial setting.

```
est = EstimatedProcess[RandomFunction[pr, {0, 100}, 100], proc2[3], 
  proc[3]]

ListLinePlot[Flatten[Abs[(pr[[2]] - est[[2]])]]]
```

[image: 2]

This error is an unacceptable level.

Comment: @kglr Thank you very much. I corrected the question.